# Source generator with physical files on disk causing ambiguity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csharp-source-generator

I'm working on a project where I want to generate cs classes based on JSON file that defines a set of exceptions. I looked into different options and trying source generator now. In my project, I want to generate the files and have them under my JSON file in the hierarchy not under analyzers (default behavior). For that I used :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>true</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>GeneratedFiles</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm facing two issues now with my project, first is whenever I try to deserialize the json file (additional file) to my own model using Newtonsoft, I get this error.

```
CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'BaseExceptionGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

The second issue, when I build and generate the files under generated folder, I'll have the same files (one under analyzers and one under this folder) which cause ambiguity whenever I try to call a method of the generated code.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0111  Type 'Hello' already defines a member called 'Display' with the same parameter types    SourceGeneratorTest ..\SourceGeneratorTest\SourceGeneratorTest\Generators\SoruceGenerator.BaseExceptionGenerator\BaseException.cs   9   Active
```

Code repo: https://github.com/KhaledSamir/SourceGeneratorTest

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who came accross same issues, I found out that the solutions for the issues are:

1. > CSC : warning CS8785: Generator 'BaseExceptionGenerator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'`

Followed the [cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages) and got it fixed.

2. > Error   CS0111  Type 'Hello' already defines a member called 'Display' with the same parameter types    SourceGeneratorTest ..\SourceGeneratorTest\SourceGeneratorTest\Generators\SoruceGenerator.BaseExceptionGenerator\BaseException.cs   9   Active`

Had to remove it from the compile, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#BKMK_RemoveAttribute) out. Basically did something like :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="$(CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath)/**/*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```